# How do I change the background line color in a chart?

Tags: apache-flex, charts, flex3

I can't seem to find out how to change the background horizontal (and vertical) line colors in a Line chart. Here's what I have so far:

```
<mx:LineChart width="100%" height="100%" dataProvider="{dataSet}">
    <mx:series>
        <mx:LineSeries showDataEffect="{eff}" yField="x" />
    </mx:series>
</mx:LineChart>
```

[image: line chart with white background lines]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You define a GridLines object inside the background elements property of the chart like so:

```
<mx:LineChart width="100%" height="100%" dataProvider="{dataSet}">

    <mx:backgroundElements>
        <mx:GridLines gridDirection="both"/>
    </mx:backgroundElements>

</mx:LineChart>
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingSDK/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7c45.html